# ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='codeload.github.com', port=443)

Tags: python, brownie

1. I tried to compile a **brownie project** with dependecies:

```
dependencies:
  # the pattern is <organization/repo>@<version>
  - smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1
compiler:
  solc:
    remappings:
      - '@chainlink=smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1'
```

2. but i faced with error:

```
D:\GIT\Web3InPython\Lottery>brownie compile -a
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Brownie v1.19.2 - Python development framework for Ethereum

  File "C:\Users\Alex\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\_cli\__main__.py", line 64, in main
    importlib.import_module(f"brownie._cli.{cmd}").main()
  File "C:\Users\Alex\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\_cli\compile.py", line 50, in main
    proj = project.load()
  File "C:\Users\Alex\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\main.py", line 780, in load
    return Project(name, project_path)
  File "C:\Users\Alex\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\main.py", line 188, in __init__
    self.load()
  File "C:\Users\Alex\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\main.py", line 257, in load
    self._compile(changed, self._compiler_config, False)
  File "C:\Users\Alex\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\main.py", line 90, in _compile
    _install_dependencies(self._path)
  File "C:\Users\Alex\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\main.py", line 786, in _install_dependencies
    install_package(package_id)
  File "C:\Users\Alex\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\main.py", line 808, in install_package
    return _install_from_github(package_id)
  File "C:\Users\Alex\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\main.py", line 880, in _install_from_github
    _stream_download(download_url, str(install_path.parent), headers)
  File "C:\Users\Alex\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\main.py", line 1042, in _stream_download
    response = requests.get(download_url, stream=True, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Users\Alex\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 73, in get
    return request("get", url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Alex\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Alex\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 587, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Alex\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 723, in send
    history = [resp for resp in gen]
  File "C:\Users\Alex\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 723, in <listcomp>
    history = [resp for resp in gen]
  File "C:\Users\Alex\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 266, in resolve_redirects
    resp = self.send(
  File "C:\Users\Alex\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 701, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Alex\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 563, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='codeload.github.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts/legacy.zip/refs/tags/1.1.1 (Caused by SSLError(CertificateError("hostname 'codeload.github.com' doesn't match either of 'dns.google', 'dns.google.com', '*.dns.google.com', '8888.google', 'dns64.dns.google', '8.8.8.8', '8.8.4.4', '2001:4860:4860:0:0:0:0:8888', '2001:4860:4860:0:0:0:0:8844', '2001:4860:4860:0:0:0:0:6464', '2001:4860:4860:0:0:0:0:64'")))
```

Could you help me?

P.S

1. I tried VPN (isn't work)
2. Change dep (isn't work)

I expexct to resolve this issue with dependencies for brownie

Comment: `SSLError(CertificateError("hostname 'codeload.github.com' doesn't match either of 'dns.google', 'dns.go ... ` feels like you are behind some sort of of a proxy  or very bad DNS server that redirects your request to google - connection opens, ssl certificate is fetched but verification fails because hostname entries in that certificate do not match codeload.github.com

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you either you are not connected to internet or your connection is not stable enough, but I'm not really sure. Personally, whenever I have such issue is because of that.